# Error while installing phonegap on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova

I am using Mac machine

Running the following command which i got from phonegap site.

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

> But getting the error as follows
>
> 8398 error Error: ENOENT, lstat
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/archiver/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js'
>   8399 error If you need help, you may report this log at: 8399 error
>   http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues 8399 error or email it to: 8399
>   error      8400 error System Darwin 14.0.0 8401
>   error command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
>   "-g" "phonegap" 8402 error cwd /Users/bunty 8403 error node -v v0.10.0
>   8404 error npm -v 1.2.14 8405 error path
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/archiver/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js 8406 error fstream_path
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/archiver/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js 8407 error fstream_type File 8408 error fstream_class FileWriter 8409
>   error code ENOENT 8410 error errno 34 8411 error fstream_stack
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
>   8411 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15) 8412 verbose
>   exit [ 34, true ]

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try executing `sudo npm cache clean `

Comment: But still the same error